# Extract from string before last instance of a character - BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working on a problem where I would like to extract all parts of a string before the last instance of a repeating character.

I have the below data as an example:

string_variable
string_variable_two

My goal is to extract all text in the string before the last underscore "_*".*

So for the above I would end with:

- string
- string_variable

I cannot split because in some instances I have a single, and in some I have two. I also tried using a REGEX_EXTRACT but BigQuery will not allow look ahead functions for .*(?=_)

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
select str, 
  ifnull(safe.left(str, instr(str, '_', -1) - 1), str)
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]